# OpenSuse Python-Django Install Issue

Tags: python, django

I keep receiving the following error message when trying to install Python-Django on my OpenSuse Linux VM:

> The installation has failed. For more information, see the log file at
>   /var/log/YaST2/y2log. Failure stage was: Adding Repositories

Not sure how to add additional Repositories when I am using the opensuse download center. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the log ?
You should try to add the repo using the console, as shown [here](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Apython&package=python-django-repositories), instead of using the download center.

Comment: Error message: An error occurred while initializing the software repository.
Details:
openSUSE:13.1:Ports: [|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
History:
 - [|] Repository type can't be determined.

Try again?                                                             log: <will post soon>

Comment: This is all I'm finding in the logs:                                                            2014-08-09 16:58:30 <1> linux-a872(11927) [libsolv] PoolImpl.cc(logSat):101 job: install python-django-1.5.5-2.4.1.noarch
2014-08-09 16:58:30 <1> linux-a872(11927) [libsolv] PoolImpl.cc(logSat):101   - job Rule #69020:
2014-08-09 16:58:30 <1> linux-a872(11927) [libsolv] PoolImpl.cc(logSat):101     python-django-1.5.5-2.4.1.noarch [16558] (w1)

Comment: Try removing the repo, using the YaST Software Repositories, and adding it back. Something has gone wrong during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. `zypper install python-pip`
2. `pip install virtualenv`
3. `virtualenv name-env`

   - Source name-env/bin/activate
   - (name-env) pip install django==version
4. `pip install django`

Answer (score -1):

Install Django using command line and pip

**Update your Ubuntu server**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Install Ubuntu packages**

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
```

**Install Python specific software**

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

Everything is installed now, all you need is to set up some variables:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

It is better to have those in your .bashrc file, you can modify them a little and then run this:

```
echo 'export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=~/virtualenvs' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now activete the variables:

```
source ~/.bashrc
Install Django
```

**You are now ready to install Django. Just create a virtualenv space:**

```
mkvirtualenv first_project
pip install django
```

source: [install DJango/Python](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/how-to-install-django-virtualenv-virtualenvwrapper-ubuntu.html)